# What is the Ad-ID (IDFA) (ASIdentifierManager) for?

Tags: ios, itunes, publish

I am publishing my first App to Itunes and I get my last question, which I do not know what to do ?

Are you using the Ad-ID (IDFA)?
It says that it provides additional class "ASIdentifierManager".
What is that for ?

- I do not want to do advertising in my app itself. ( no ad-banners in my app )
- But I like probably advertising for my app in future.

Do I need this option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not now as your app is not implementing ads. IDFA stands for “identifier for advertisers.” It’s a random, anonymous number that is assigned to a user and their device, but I have no experience with it so if your app is not using ads at the moment you don't have to check the box of IDFA.

Read more: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29032/identifier-for-advertisers-ifa-ifda

Answer (score 1):

The `ASIdentifierManager` class provides apps with access to an identifier that can be used only for `serving advertisements`, as well as a flag which indicates whether a user has limited ad tracking.

Before you submit a new app or a new version of an existing app to Apple’s App Store, note that Apple has recently updated the IDFA settings so that you must agree to their revised terms of service by selecting a check box that indicates your compliance.

for apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/index.html)

When you submit your apps with iTunes Connect, you’ll now be prompted with three checkboxes certifying your intentions to use IFA for:

- Serve advertisements within the app.
- Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement.
- Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement
  To avoid app store rejections, ensure that you select the appropriate IDFA usage check-boxes for your app and honor Apple’s “Limit Ad Tracking” requirement.

  [image]

for additional [reference](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/how-to-use-apples-identifier-for-advertisers-idfa/)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably figured it, IDFA is mainly used by advertising libraries (like AdMob, moPub) to identify users for ad targeting.

You answer the questions related to IDFA usage with every new update of your app that you send for review. If your current version does not make use of IDFA, you can safely leave those unchecked even if you're planning to use it in the future versions of your app.